# Getting aggregation to work in D9/D10 Views with CiviCRM relationships

Tags: drupal-views, civicrm-entity

Using CiviCRM Entity
commit 5295af29e5bac4575f991683b1c061b96a0e0713 (HEAD -> 8.x-3.x, origin/HEAD, origin/8.x-3.x)

Trying to get this to aggregate properly ->
[image]

But this should only show 3 rows with the final row:

Other 50-60 yrs 2

Gender is the CiviCRM Core field. Age Range is a CiviCRM Custom (select) field.

When compared to D7 -> we are noting **2 MIN()** getting injected into the query:

```
SELECT "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant"."gender_id" AS "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant_gender_id", "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3"."age_range_61" AS "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_c", "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3"."id" AS "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_c_1", COUNT(DISTINCT civicrm_participant.contact_id) AS "civicrm_participant_contact_id", MIN(civicrm_participant.id) AS "id", MIN(civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant.id) AS "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant_id"
FROM
{civicrm_participant} "civicrm_participant"
LEFT JOIN drupal_karin.civicrm_contact "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant" ON civicrm_participant.contact_id = civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant.id
LEFT JOIN drupal_karin.civicrm_value_contact_custo_3 "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3" ON civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant.id = civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3.entity_id
WHERE "civicrm_participant"."event_id" = '32'
GROUP BY civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant_gender_id, civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_c, civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_c_1
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

UPDATE:
If I remove the custom field Age Range from the equation (and only leave the native CiviCRM Core Gender field) -> then the View produces the proper count:

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is due to the relationship to the custom field:

```
"civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3"."id" AS "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_c_1",
```

From

```
LEFT JOIN drupal_karin.civicrm_value_contact_custo_3 "civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3" ON civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant.id = civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3.entity_id
```

It's being added to `GROUP BY` as `civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_c_1`.

Comment: I think the key is the missing MIN(civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_custo_3.entity_id)

Answer (score 1):

It's grouping by civicrm_contact_civicrm_participant__civicrm_value_contact_c_1 which is the custom field row id, but it's not being group_concat'd in the select. So it's going to have a row for each different contact. Or I'm not sure why it's even being included in the query.